# Sklearn Spectral Clustering error in fit_predict : k must be between 1 and the order of the square input matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm using [Spectral Clustering Library](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html) in Python and similarity matrix is its main argument. My matrix looks like:

```
[[ 1.          0.85018854  0.85091491  0.85717652]
 [ 0.85018854  1.          0.99720197  0.99732831]
 [ 0.85091491  0.99720197  1.          0.9972462 ]
 [ 0.85717652  0.99732831  0.9972462   1.        ]]
```

And my code similar to the documentation samples:

```
cl = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=4,affinity='precomputed')
y = cl.fit_predict(matrix)
```

But the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mahmood/PycharmProjects/sentence2vec/graphClustering.py", line 22, in <module>
    y = cl.fit_predict(matrix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.17.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/base.py", line 371, in fit_predict
    self.fit(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.17.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/cluster/spectral.py", line 454, in fit
    assign_labels=self.assign_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.17.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/cluster/spectral.py", line 258, in spectral_clustering
    eigen_tol=eigen_tol, drop_first=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.17.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/manifold/spectral_embedding_.py", line 254, in spectral_embedding
    tol=eigen_tol)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py", line 1507, in eigsh
    raise ValueError("k must be between 1 and the order of the "
ValueError: k must be between 1 and the order of the square input matrix.
```

I have no idea and I need to know what is the problem and maybe it's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 data points.

You request 4 clusters.

What do you expect to happen?

There is only the trivial solution (every point is different) so spectral clustering refuses to run. For sensible solutions, the number of clusters must be at least 2, and at most n-1 if you have n points, obviously.